# hosting stack panel in windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

i have a Normal Panel in my windows form Application and i want to add a stack panel which is there in WPF inside it.

Stack Panel should Consists of 2 Expander Controls inside it.

i am using Element Host to Have the stack panel and expander Control in the windows form.

i am using the Following Code:

```
       ElementHost WPF_Container = new ElementHost();
        WPF_Container.AutoSize = true;

        ElementHost WPF_Container1 = new ElementHost();
        WPF_Container1 .AutoSize = true;

        ElementHost StackPanelHost = new ElementHost();

        Expander expander1 = new Expander();
        expander1.Header = "Pipes";

        Expander Expander2 = new Expander();
        Expander2.Header = "Mountings";

        uc1 uc1 = new uc1(); // Object Creation for User Control-1
        uc2 uc2 = new uc2();  // Object Creation for User Control-2

        StackPanel Stackpanel = new StackPanel();
        Stackpanel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;


        WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        host.Child  = uc1 ;

        WindowsFormsHost host2 = new WindowsFormsHost();
        host2.Child = uc2;


        expander1.Content = host;
        Expander2.Content = host2;

        Stackpanel.Children.Add(expander1);
        Stackpanel.Children.Add(Expander2);


        // WPF_Container.Child = expander1;
        // WPF_Container1.Child = Expander2;
        StackPanelHost.Child = Stackpanel;

        panel1.Controls.Add(StackPanelHost); // Adding Stack Panel to my Winform Panel.
```

by using the above Code during Form Load Event no controls are getting added to my Windows form Panel.
How to Achieve the functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you do it:

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
StackPanel wpfPanel = new StackPanel();
host.Child = wpfPanel;
//panel1 is Windows Forms Panel
panel1.Controls.Add(host);
```

I recomend that you create the UI you need in a WPF user control and then add it to the ElementHost.

UPDATE:

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
StackPanel wpfPanel = new StackPanel();
host.Child = wpfPanel;
//panel1 is Windows Forms Panel
panel1.Controls.Add(host);
var testButton = new System.Windows.Controls.Button(){Content = "test"};
wpfPanel.Children.Add(testButton);
```

Pay attention you are using the correct namespace as windows forms as also a Button Class

Comment: I Want to Add controls Dynamically in WPF Stack Panel how to acheive it.